# String ending with character in parboiled2, when the string can contain that character

Tags: scala, peg, parboiled, parboiled2

I've come across a tricky problem writing a parboiled2 parser, which is that I need to match a portion of a line which is a string which has its end marked by a `:` character. This would be easy enough, except that the string can *contain* the `:` character.

At the moment I've got this which treats the string as a group of colon-terminated strings and concats them, but this consumes the trailing `:` which I don't want as the trailing `:` is not part of the string itself.

```
def address = rule { capture(oneOrMore(zeroOrMore(noneOf(":")) ~ ":")) }
```

I feel like I should be using `&(":")` somewhere in here but I'm struggling to work that in while matching the interstitial `:` characters.

Example successful matches (as part of a longer string):

- `localhost:` -> `localhost`
- `1:::` -> `1::`
- `:::` -> `::`

Mismatches:

- `:`

Any suggestions would be welcome, even if it's "you can't do this" so I can stop racking my brains.

---

The context for this is parsing the `bind` setting in an HAProxy configuration file. Some examples of valid strings given the following (simplified) case classes are:

```
case class Bind(endpoint: Endpoint, params: Seq[String])
case class Endpoint(address: Option[String], port: Option[Int])
```

- `bind :80` -> `Bind(Endpoint(None, Some(80)), Seq())`
- `bind localhost:80` -> `Bind(Endpoint(Some("localhost"), Some(80)), Seq())`
- `bind localhost` -> `Bind(Endpoint(Some("localhost"), None), Seq())`
- `bind :80 param1` -> `Bind(Endpoint(None, Some(80)), Seq("param1")))`

In other words, if there is a string it needs to be terminated before the final `:` as that's the indicator that there is a port. The `endpoint` rule looks something like this:

```
def endpoint = rule { optional(address) ~ optional(':' ~ int) ~> Endpoint }
```

Ultimately the matchable string for the endpoint is terminated by either a space or the end of the line, so one option would be to just capture until the space and then parse the string separately, but I was hoping to do it within the main parser.

Comment: Can you give an example of a valid "longer string" and what you would expect to get from that string (ie: the successful matches)?

Comment: @David I've added some context while trying to keep the problem relatively isolated. The real case is rather more complex ([code](https://github.com/gregbeech/haproxy-config/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/gregbeech/haproxy/ConfigParser.scala#L55), [spec](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-bind)) but hopefully what's there should be enough to understand the issue.

Comment: So you could have a line of `bind 1:::80`, and you want to output `Bind(Endpoint(Some("1::"), Some(80)), Seq())`? Is this a good case where your problem arises?

Comment: Yes, that's a good example of the specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the following should work for your problem description:

```scala
def noColons = rule { zeroOrMore(noneOf(":")) }
def colonWithNext = rule { ':' ~ &(noColons ~ ':') }
def address = rule { capture(oneOrMore(noColons).separatedBy(colonWithNext)) ~ ':' }
```

The problem with your code was the usage of the ~ combinator, since an expression like `A ~ B` only matches if at first A matches and then B matches, but it would mismatch at B if rule B *is part of* rule A. There's no backtracking involved here, the parboiled2 parser only backtracks for alternatives.

So, in this case you have to make sure to consume the ':' only if there's another one following it.

Comment: Great, thanks -- I was starting to get somewhere along these lines but the combination of `capture` and `separatedBy` was what did the trick (I was discarding the delimiters). Also I was trying to write it in a single rule whereas splitting it out makes things much clearer.